# In VB.NET how do I get a button's text to change in its own event handler?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to change the text drawn on a Button at the beginning of the click event handler. No matter what I do the text doesn't change until after the event handler method finishes. I've tried calling the button's update, refresh, and invalidate methods and also tried calling Application.DoEvents afterward.

The only thing that works, which I don't want to do, is to set up a timer so that the click event handler ends, the button text updates, then the timer ticks and THEN I do everything else I wanted to do in the click handler in the timer tick handler instead...

Comment: that is how Windows works.  It cant/wont pause the processing of the click even to process the paint even you caused then come back to where it left off in the click event.

Comment: If you post what you've tried and describe your end goal, someone might be able to offer an alternative solution to that fits your needs.

Comment: Try btw.Refresh() inside the event handler.

Comment: In the event handler you could change the button text and then create a new thread to run the processing that needs to be done.  This would allow the handler sub to finish ~immediately and your button text would get updated, meanwhile in the background the processing is running.  This is what you would want to do anyway if the processing will take any substantial time so that the UI stays responsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your user interface "hangs" while your long operation is executed on the UI thread. You could solve this by running your long operation in a background thread, for example, by using a `BackgroundWorker` in your button event handler:

```
Dim bw As New BackgroundWorker()

AddHandler bw.DoWork,
    Sub(sender, args)
        ' Do your lengthy stuff here -- this will happen in a separate thread.
        ' If you want to do UI operations here, you need to use Control.Invoke.
    End Sub

AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted,
    Sub(sender, args)
        ' We are back in the UI thread here.
        If args.Error IsNot Nothing Then    ' If an exception occurred during DoWork,
            MsgBox(args.Error.ToString())   ' do your error handling here
        End If

        ' Re-enable your button and change the text back here:
        ...
    End Sub

' Disable your button and change the text here:
...

bw.RunWorkerAsync()   ' Start the Background Worker
```

(Of course, if you don't like `AddHandler`, using an instance `WithEvents` variable for the BackgroundWorker and the `Handles` keyword is just as fine and more typical for VB.)

Note that, in this case, the user can interact with your user interface while the operation is running. This can be a good thing (you can add an "interrupt" button that sets a flag which is checked in your long operation), but you need to make sure that no bad things can happen, e.g. deactivate the button, so that the same operation cannot be started twice.

Comment: You're right, the stuff I was doing inside the click handler took a long time and was better done in it's own thread rather than hanging up the UI thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All UI updates have to come from the UI thread. The event handler is called (or invoked) by the UI thread when it detects an event (such as button pressed) occurs. The UI thread takes care of updating the UI after the events.

Comment: So what I want to do is force one UI event (to change the button text) to be processed in the middle of another that is currently being processed (the buttons click handler), possible?